# WPF Window size have monitor size

Tags: c#, wpf, window, monitor

I am new in WPF and I want to make a window that has max sizes (monitor sizes).

The Window's XAML code is this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Stop"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Stop" Height="{Binding}" Width="{Binding}" Background="Black" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="260" d:DesignWidth="348" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Ok" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,36,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBlock Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,16,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Introduceti parola:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" />
        <PasswordBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,36,0,0" Name="passwordBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The C# code that open this window is this:

```
Stop a = new Stop();                   
a.Show();
a.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
a.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

How can I set window size to monitor size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this in code-behind:

```
a.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

and remove `SizeToContent` from your `XAML`.

With this code:

```
a.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
a.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

you will have problems when using secondary screen with different resolution.

Answer (score 2):

above comment is working. i did below:-
written in mainwindow.xaml.cs:-

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```